# Doc2vec: How can I manually modify a trained vector in a Doc2Vec gensim model?

Tags: python, vector, doc2vec

I would like to **replace a specific Doc2Vec vector** created by a Doc2vec model with another one, with different weights.

These are the weights of existing vector (just some of the 800 real weights):

```
array([ 1.72976881e-01,  2.44364753e-01, -9.90936995e-01, -1.03020036e+00,
       -1.41046381e+00,  1.00970473e-02, -1.84546992e-01,  3.77230316e-01,
        9.20825064e-01, -2.61079431e-01,  7.51454890e-01, -1.15353882e+00,
       -9.96422302e-03,  1.65010715e+00,  5.63869551e-02, -4.25169647e-01],
      dtype=float32)
```

I'd like to replace them with these ones:

```
array([ 1.54585496e-01,  2.22857013e-01, -8.88102770e-01, -9.27794874e-01,
       -1.27402091e+00, -5.38651831e-04, -1.63646400e-01,  3.38727772e-01,
        8.28402698e-01, -2.29774594e-01,  6.77914560e-01, -1.04013634e+00,
       -1.37407500e-02,  1.48667252e+00,  5.83136305e-02, -3.88587236e-01]
      dtype=float32)
```

I tried to add a new vector to my model with this code:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load('mymodel.doc2vec')
model.docvecs.add(entities=["88763"], weights=[new_vector])
```

I'm not getting any error, still when I call back that "88763" vector I see that it hasn't been updated:

```
model.docvecs["88763"]

array([ 1.72976881e-01,  2.44364753e-01, -9.90936995e-01, -1.03020036e+00,
       -1.41046381e+00,  1.00970473e-02, -1.84546992e-01,  3.77230316e-01,
        9.20825064e-01, -2.61079431e-01,  7.51454890e-01, -1.15353882e+00,
       -9.96422302e-03,  1.65010715e+00,  5.63869551e-02, -4.25169647e-01],
      dtype=float32)
```

Could someone please help me in some way?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your `mymodel.doc2vec` or something we can test with?

Comment: Reading through the [docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#usage-examples) it looks like it may be of the form `model.docvecs['doc003'] = new_vector` but I'd have to see some example mymodel.doc2vec to see the object structure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't load a `Doc2Vec` model with `Word2Vec'. So load it instead with:

```
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec.load('mymodel.doc2vec')
```

Once loaded, you should be able to modify any existing entry via direct assignment to a bracket-accessed entry, eg:

```
model.docvecs['88763'] = new_vector
```

(You would chiefly use `add()` to add vectors for keys that aren't already there. But it might also work to replace existing vectors in a batch if you supply the non-default `replace=True` parameter in addition to the list-of-entities and list-of-vectors.)

**Update:** The above is supposed to work, but there's a [pending bug](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2683) at the moment (November 2019, `gensim-3.8.1`) where it won't.

In the meantime, to modify one specific existing vector, you can act on the raw `vectors_docs` property, and look up the index-position to change yourself. For example:

```
slot = model.docvecs.int_index('88763', 
                               model.docvecs.doctags,
                               model.docvecs.max_rawint)
model.docvecs.vectors_docs[slot] = new_vector
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice , but it still doesn't work. In fact , even when i try something else  like model.docvecs['88763'] = model.docvecs['88763']*2  vector replacement does not happen at all

Comment: Aha, looking closer, I see that these approaches that should work (assignment to `[…]`-access or `add(…, replace=True)`) haven't ben properly implemented for the `.docvecs` object (at least through the latest `gensim` release as of November 2019, `gensim-3.8.1`). I've filed a bug report –  https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2683 – and will update my answer shortly with a workaround until that's fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your help , i see you did not receive any answer on GH as now. Do you think i can manage another way to modify an existing vector ? This would be very helpful for my purposes

Comment: What's wrong with the code suggestion in my '*Update*`, using that 2-step process? It should work currently.

Comment: really sorry i didn't read the update ,  however im'getting  this error : "int_index() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'doctags' and 'max_rawint'" --> maybe   i must set these arguments in some way?

Comment: Sorry, yes, some disastrously broken changes modified this utility method to inexplicably require extra passed-in arguments (that are always already in the object). I'll update my answer with what's necessary in current gensim-3.8.1, but this should get a lot better in the future.